# Julia matrix slicing

Tags: matrix, julia

How do I slice a Julia matrix so that I get the first x rows?

I've tried

```
slicedMatrix = matrix[1 : x ; :]
```

but I keep getting this error

ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching typed_vcat(::Array{Float64,2}, ::StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}, ::Colon)

Using commas instead of semicolons doesn't help.

Comment: _"Using commas instead of semicolons doesn't help."_ Using a comma instead of a semicolon is the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `x` is defined it should just be `slicedMatrix = matrix[1 : x, :]`.